# Массив в PostgreSQL и ошибка

Tags: массивы, postgresql, sql

Создаю в посгресовской таблице числовое поле типа массив:

```
CREATE TABLE aaa (
  test int[][]
);
```

Без проблем выполняется такая вставка:

```
INSERT INTO aaa (test) VALUES
('{{4,5,7,9}}'),
('{{2},{3},{4}}'),
(NULL),
('{8,9}');
```

Есть сильное желание выполнить вставку:

```
INSERT INTO aaa (test) VALUES
('{{1},{3},{2},{},{}}'),
('{{1},{4,5,8},{},{},{}}'),
('{{1},{6},{},{},{}}'),
('{{1},{7,9},{},{},{}}');
```

...но возвращается ошибка: *"для многомерных массивов должны задаваться вложенные определения в соответствии с размерностью"*:

Не могу понять, как это сделать. Логику PostgreSQL в отношении массивов тоже понять не могу. Буду признателен как за исправление кода и объяснение, почему строки из первого примера c INSERT пишутся, а из последнего - нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
INSERT INTO aaa (test) VALUES
('{{1}, {3}, {2}, {NULL}, {NULL}}'),
('{{1}, {4,5,8}, {NULL,NULL,NULL}, {NULL,NULL,NULL}, {NULL,NULL,NULL}}'),
('{{1}, {6}, {NULL}, {NULL}, {NULL}}'),
('{{1}, {7,9}, {NULL,NULL}, {NULL,NULL}, {NULL,NULL}}');
```

Количество элементов в массиве **может один раз (и только один раз) вырасти в рамках одной строки**; в предыдущие подмассивы автоматически будет добавлен NULL. Но **уменьшиться уже не может**. Иными словами, это работает:

```
INSERT INTO aaa (test) VALUES ('{{1}, {2,3}}');
INSERT INTO aaa (test) VALUES ('{{1}, {2,3,4}, {5,6,7}}');
```

А такие запросы не выполнятся:

```
INSERT INTO aaa (test) VALUES ('{{1,2}, {3}}'); 
INSERT INTO aaa (test) VALUES ('{{1}, {2,3}, {4,5,6}}');
```

Вернемся к исправленному запросу на вставку.

- Строки 1 и 3: во вложенных массивах по одному элементу;
- Строка 2: второй вложенный массив содержит три элемента, поэтому все последующие элементы должны иметь три элемента (там, где данных нет, ставим NULL);
- Строка 4: второй массив содержит два элемента, поэтому последующие вложенные массивы тоже содержат два элемента.

Влияние оказывают только предшествующие массивы в рамках строки. Поэтому нет необходимости писать три элемента во вложенный массив во всех строках.

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости, не может быть элемента массива без значения. Может, попробовать `NULL` как пустое значение?

Comment: Хитрость в том, что в рамках одного массива все подмассивы должны быть одного размера. Соответственно, может потребоваться несколько NULL.

Comment: Спасибо за просвещение. В принципе, логичная работа с массивами.